# 'nc' using ~100% CPU when transferring a FIFO file

Tags: cron, performance, netcat, fifo, mpd

On the server which is always connected I’m using this in a crontab:

```
@reboot nc -k -l 1337 < /tmp/fifo.fifo
```

On the client which is not always on the network or switched on I’m using this command:

```
nc -d $IP_OF_SERVER 1337 > /tmp/fifo.fifo & $SOME_COMMAND
```

The server listens always for a connection on the specified port (thanks to the -k parameter), the client just connects to the server when it needs to.

I’m using this for MPD and its FIFO visualizer. MPD runs on a remote host, but my MPD client (ncmpcpp) runs locally.

*This is the important part of the ncmpcpp config on the local host:*

```
mpd_host = "$IP_OF_SERVER"
visualizer_fifo_path = "/tmp/fifo.fifo"
```

*This is the important part of the mpd config on the remote server:*

```
audio_output {
        […]
        path    "/tmp/fifo.fifo"
        […]
}
```

***Running the 'nc' command on my local machine seems to use a very high amount of resources … ~100% of my CPU performance.***

[image: CPU]

[image: Energy]

Any ideas where the problem is? Or if this is normal and how I would improve this whole scenario?

Unfortunately it’s not possible to just specify a network-path for visualizer_fifo_path, like:

```
visualizer_fifo_path = "$IP_OF_SERVER:/tmp/fifo.fifo"
```

And it’s also not possible to mount the remote host via NFS and then use the FIFO which is mounted via NFS.

Here’s some output from dtruss:

```
$ >> ps aux | grep 1337
user            96823  95,2  0,0  2433292    576 s003  R+   12:16PM  37:27.77 nc -d 192.168.2.42 1337
user            96821   0,0  0,0  2447044   1084 s003  Ss+  12:16PM   0:00.00 bash -c nc -d 192.168.2.42 1337 > /tmp/volumio.fifo & ncmpcpp -c /Users/user/.ncmpcpp/config-volumio -s visualizer

$ >> sudo dtruss -p 96821
SYSCALL(args)            = return

$ >> sudo dtruss -p 96823
dtrace: 353433 dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
SYSCALL(args)            = return
select(0x4, 0x7FFF5D031F90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)               = 1 0
select(0x4, 0x7FFF5D031F90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)               = 1 0
select(0x4, 0x7FFF5D031F90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)               = 2 0
read(0x3, "\260\377N\377\022\377\325\376X\376J\376\233\375\253\375\311\374\332\374\262\374\276\374\234\374\232\374_\374L\374\217\374v\374\321\374\255\374\006\375\341\374\a\375\372\374\314\374\323\374\305\374\306\374k\374z\374\267\373\355\373u\373\251\373s\373\230\373\200\373\271\373\363\373\026\374^\374h\3746\374P\374\333\373\375\373q\373\225\373\270\372\354\372\270\371\364\371'\371g\371\036\371\\\371b\371\217\371\331\371\371\371\0", 0x400)           = 1024 0
write(0x1, "\260\377N\377\022\377\325\376X\376J\376\233\375\253\375\311\374\332\374\262\374\276\374\234\374\232\374_\374L\374\217\374v\374\321\374\255\374\006\375\341\374\a\375\372\374\314\374\323\374\305\374\30
select(0x4, 0x7FFF5D031F90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)               = 1 0
select(0x4, 0x7FFF5D031F90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)               = 1 0
select(0x4, 0x7FFF5D031F90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)               = 1 0
[…]
```

PS: Maybe the problem is that 'nc' is started in 'tmux' together with 'ncmpcpp' …

```
tmux split-window -t "$session":1 -v -p 28 "nc -d $IP_OF_SERVER 1337 > /tmp/volumio.fifo & ncmpcpp -c $HOME/.ncmpcpp/config-volumio -s visualizer"
```

***How would I permanently run 'nc -d $IP_OF_SERVER 1337' in the background, maybe also started by a crontab? Is there something like the '-k' parameter for connecting to a server?***

Comment: Probably a bug in `nc`, what do you see if you trace the system calls, which `nc` is making? (Might be it is in an infinite loop of system calls each returning `EAGAIN`)

Comment: I tried to provide the information you wanted with 'dtruss'. Please let me know if you need further information. And please tell me, how I can get that information (never did things like those before).

Comment: I'll leave this question for somebody who understands the `dtruss` output format better than me. The back-to-back `select` calls do look suspicious, but I can't figure out what the exact arguments and return values are in this case.

Comment: Is there some other tool on OSX which gives you useful information?

Comment: sys_select(maxfd=4, readfd=<stuff>, write=except=NULL, timeout=NULL) (read-poll-loop), returns 1 or 2 for number of sockets ready. It's odd that when the socket is ready, it doesn't perform a read operation right away.